# Re-arranging the format of csv in Python

Tags: python, arrays, csv, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I tried doing what I can to solve this, the movie titles just won't move up. The problem is at the 2nd block in the for loop.. This is the function I wrote.

```
def writeFile(filename, movie_titles):
    with open(filename, 'w') as f:
        headers = "No., Title\n"
        f.write(headers)
        i = 0
    
        for title in movie_titles:
            while i < len(movie_titles[0:]): i = i + 1; f.write(str(i) + '\n')
            f.write(', '+ "%s\n" % title.replace(',', '') + '\n')
        f.close()
```

[image: This is the image of what the preview looks like]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another answer has a more straightforward and pythonic method, but for your specific code, this would solve it:

```
def writeFile(filename, movie_titles):
    with open(filename, 'w') as f:
        headers = "No., Title\n"
        f.write(headers)
        i = 0
    
        for title in movie_titles:
            i = i + 1
            f.write(str(i) + ', '+ "%s\n" % title.replace(',', '') + '\n')
```

Note that the final `f.close()` is not needed. The `with` command takes care of that.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `enumerate()` in for loop to get index. For example:

```
def writeFile(filename, movie_titles):
    with open(filename, 'w') as f:
        f.write("No., Title\n")

        for i, title in enumerate(movie_titles, 1):
            f.write('{},{}\n'.format(i, title.replace(',', '')))
```

---

Note: To create CSV file look at [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/csv.html) module.

Answer (score 1):

You got your loops mixed up a bit. your code goes into the for-loop and iterates over all movies, during the first iteration it executes the while-loop and only after that is finished the for-loop is continued.
I would suggest something like this:

```
def writeFile(filename, movie_titles):
with open(filename, 'w') as f:
    headers = "No., Title\n"
    f.write(headers)
    i = 0

    for i in range(len(movie_titles)):
        f.write(str(i+1) + ',')
        f.write("%s\n" % movie_titles[i].replace(',', ''))
    f.close()
```

the for loop iterates over all numbers from 0 to length of movielist - 1
then the number is written, here you add 1 so that your list starts with 1
after that you write your movie title. i assumed your movielist variable is a list and thus you can index this list by list[index], this index is in our case i and it's highest value corresponds to the last element of movie list.
also you had too many newlines because you only need one new line per line.

one could probably also write numbers and movienames separately but then you would need to specify which row of the file you are writing to.